# Menu CSS Responsive Problema posición y movimiento

Tags: javascript, css3, menú, responsive

Estoy intentando hacer un menu responsive algo diferente a como normal lo suelo hacer:

El icono para habilitar el menu lo tengo fijo en bottom-derecha.

Al pinchar, me muestra el menu de la siguiente manera:

[image: Imagen del menu]

El desplazamiento, hacia la izquierda para mostrarlo. y para irse, se va a la izquierda. **Intento que se desplace a la derecha para volver a esconderse ** por ofrecer una mejor "calidad".

Además me gustaría saber como puedo hacer que no se ve así, me ocupe el "alto entero" del sidebar que se crea.

Por último, pondré mi código (CSS3)

```
  .menu_bar {
    display:block;
    width:15%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255,.8);
  }

  .menu_bar .bt-menu {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .menu_bar span {
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
  }

  header {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
  }

  nav {
    width: 95%;
    position: fixed;
    left:80%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  header nav ul li {
    background: rgba(52, 152, 219,.9);
    display: block;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  }
```

Ahora el JS que lo ejecuta:

```
$(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1;

function main () {
    $('.menu_bar').click(function(){
        if (contador == 1) {
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '10%'
            });
            contador = 0;
        } else {
            contador = 1;
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '-100%'
            });
        }
    });

    $('.submenu').click(function(){
        $(this).children('.children').slideToggle();
    });
}
```

Agradecería mucho la colaboración de quien le apetezca ayudarme con este reto.

- - Edito porque se me ha pasado el problema de los más graves:

**Al hacer clic en menú, te sube hasta arriba de todo y muestra el menú.**

HTML:

Menu

- Inicio
  Programación
- Diseño Web
- Tiendas online
- Aplicaciones Móvil
- Programación a medida

```
        <li class="submenu">
            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-globe"></span>Posicionamiento Web<span class="caret icon-arrow-down6"></span></a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li><a href="posicionamiento.php">Posicionamiento SEO <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="posicionamientosem.php">Campañas en AdWords <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="emailmarketing.php">Email Marketing <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="marketing-redes-sociales.php">Marketing en redes sociales <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="auditoria-seo.php">Auditorías Competencia <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="submenu">
            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></span>Soporte Informático<span class="caret icon-arrow-down6"></span></a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li><a href="gestion-hardware.php">Mantenimiento de Hardware <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="gestion-software.php">Mantenimiento de Software <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="gestion-redes.php">Diseño y Gestión Red Local <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="servidores-dedicados.php">Servidores dedicados <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="seguridad.php">Copias de seguridad <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="almacenamiento.php">Almacenamiento <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span></a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-trophy"></span>Proyectos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Javier, deberías añadir también el HTML para crear un [mcve]. Puedes crear un snippet ejecutable en la propia pregunta pulsando en el icono `<>` del editor, y así podríamos ver el problema directamente en la publicación y sería más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Seria bueno ver también el html, prueba agregandole la propiedad `margin-bottom: -50%;` a la clase ".menu_bar"

Comment: Hola, disculpa, acabo de añadir el HTML

Comment: No me había dado cuenta de que esta pregunta era la original y te respondí en otra.... No dupliques preguntas, por favor. No te ayudan a encontrar una respuesta más rápido y sólo crean ruido.